# How to hide/change a div element content by jquery-1.11.0.min version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

i have a div element as following that load in my vbulletin theme at the end of codes(exactly before `</body>` tag), How can i remove this div by adding a javascript code? or change its content? jquery-1.11.0.min loads in my theme so if possible share the solution with me that can do this with this jquery version.

div element:

```
<div style="position: absolute!important;z-index: 99999999999999999999!important;font-family: Yekan;display: block!important;color: #FFF!important;width: 100%!important;text-align: center;background: #2B2D3B!important;padding: 1px 0 7px 0;" id="dgh">
طراحی شده با 
<i class="icon-heart"></i> 
توسط 
<a href="http://aliz1212.ir">علیزاده</a>
 در 
<a href="http://www.iranforum.ir">ایران فروم</a> 
.</div>
```

consider that i cant insert the javascript code after the div tag  and only its possible to add the javacode code before the div element, also i know that i cant override the inline important style with css. thanks

Comment: i cant edit the div to change it's style, i tried some javascript codes and none of theme worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // find the last div in body
  var lastDiv = $('#dgh');

  // remove the div ...
  lastDiv.remove();

  // ... or change it's content
  lastDiv.html('new content goes hier');
});
```

Comment: The id attribute I saw later after my first attempt. I updated my answer to use the id to select the div.

Comment: @sajjad_safari  Don't forget to mark this as the answer or upvote if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple just use your id to remove or update the element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dgh').remove();
  //or
  $('#dgh').html('Your content goes here');
});
```